# SHA1 for google map release key is showing some encrypted text

Tags: android, google-maps, windows-10, sha1

I was working with google map. In debug mode, it was fantastic. For release mode I tried to get the release SHA1 key from my windows10 hp probook. But i got some encrypted text instead of SHA1.

My command is as follows:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias razon** -keystore E:\keystore\keystore.jks
```

The output was as follows along with some unknown signs that are unable to write here:

```
 0S10 U8810dhaka10Udhaka10U
 410608143654Z0S10 U8810dhaka10Udhaka10U
```

Then I created another API key for google map from Developer console with a SHA1, used previously in another project. With this API, the map is working in release mode but only in my device(Nexus 5, os6.1).

**My Questions**

1. How can I get the actual SHA1?
2. What can I do now? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `keytool -list -v` command ([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html#keytool_option_list)):

```
keytool -list -v -alias razon** -keystore E:\keystore\keystore.jks
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got the SHA1 key. But what about my second part, i couldn't understand why the SHA1 key of another project worked for me and only in my device?

Answer (score 0):

More easiest way:
[image]

Double click on the **signingReport**. You will see your debug and release SHA1 fingerprint. But before that you must have to set the keystore file from Project structure.

In order to do that, go to ***File>Project Structures...>app>Sigining>+***
After that give a name and locate the store file(keystore or .jks) and provide your alias and password.
Then Click OK.

Then again go to ***File>Project Structures...>app>Build Types*** and there you will see **debug** and **release**. Select each of them and change the **Sigining Config** value to you newly created one.