# How to run debug and release versions easily

Tags: android, debugging, release

Well, in my application, I use Google Maps and Google Sign In API, I was running debug version for tests and more tests, then I made my release version and the keys didn't work... I've gone to Google API Console and caught another key for Google Maps,

and for Google Sign In, I had to make a new SHA1 of my keystore.jks, got a file named "client-secret.json" and put into my app's folder, then I've compiled it in release mode again and it worked...

Now I need to compile debug versions for more tests, cause it's a lot faster than release, and Google Sign In isn't working again

What do I gotta do to get it working in debug mode again? And is there a way to switch between debug and release mode easily, given that I have to change files to achieve that?

Comment: I have a fixed solution for it. Please visit this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39598876/sha1-for-google-map-release-key-is-showing-some-encrypted-text/39600171#39600171

Comment: I've done that using @Budiu's solution, thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android Studio:

Right click on the `src` folder `-> New -> XML -> Values XML File`

It will show a screen like this:

[image: Android studio add XM file screen]

select like above, `donottranslate` and `debug`. On the generated file you can add the debug key to maps.

Repeat the process but, on the screen above use Target Source Set: `release` and add the release key in there.

I'm not sure where you're putting this JSON file, but you after adding the maps key you can check that a `debug` and `release` folders were created in your project structure. So you just repeat the same concept from the XML file.

The debug JSON goes into the debug folder and the release JSON goes into the "release" folder. Both in the same order that they currently are in your `main` folder.

If you're not using Android Studio, you should change to Android Studio as Eclipse plugin is not supported anymore.

Anything else you want to make different between debug and release can be done on the same way. .java files, drawables, strings, anything.

Comment: I've just done this... But my google json files (google-services.json for debug mode, and client-secret.json for release), was inside "MyProject/app/" folder... I've put the google-services.json into MyProject/app/src/debug/, and the release file client-secret.json into MyProject/app/src/release/... and Sign In is still not working... Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: I've figured out what was going on... Both versions need google-services.json, and only the release version needs client-secret.json... Putting those in the right respective folders made it work...

Comment: I was gonna check about the `google-service.json` on the office, but I'm happy you made it work.